# Zxing - My app does not want to start the camera

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

first of all i will introduce myself. I am a young student from austria who is new to Android programming. My Project is to write a Barcode scanner and if you scan a product you get more information about it.

So lets get started with the real problem now:

I have done everything what the tutorials say and it works. The ZXING-Source Code is now a libary for my own Project and ofcourse it is included.

When i export the Android project as a FILENAME.APK and copy it to my SGS3 everything works.
Then i install the apk on my phone and start running the app. When i press the scan barcode button which calls the "onClick"-Method it does nothing. Android says to me the application has ben stopped.

I dont know which function i have to use. Should i use the IntentIntegrator methods or the intent methods to be able to scan a code. ( I know i cant use both in my Method, pasted it here to show your my problem )

```
    public void onClick(final View view)
 {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.initiateScan();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Post your stack trace from when it crashes.  The Intent should work, ive used it dozens of times.  Post it bellow your code and I will help

Comment: What do you mean with stack trace ? I will upload my Project for you

Comment: First, make sure you have LogCat enabled: in Eclipse, Goto Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat. Then when your app says "Application has been stopped" check the error logs, and post them here (that is, if Selvins answer doesnt fix your problem)

Comment: If i want to test my Android app i export it as an apk file and run it on my own phone. Can i enable LogCat on my Phone to see the errors ?

Comment: AH well first of all, you definitely don't have to export it every time.  You are using eclipse, right? You should be able to run the app in debug mode without having to export it.  An added bonus is you get logs too

Comment: Yes i use eclipse, but if i want to run my app on the AVD i cant use the "camera". But i will now run my App in Eclipse and post the LogCat

Comment: Through ADB you should be able to debug over USB to your PHONE...this is definitely a priority for you at this point

Comment: Ok i will try to get that ADB thing asap.

Comment: So here is a Link with two Pictures, there you can see the Debug Code LINK: http://imgur.com/zgpLH,KOeQ6#0     I was not able to poste the whole code here, i hope you dont mind

Comment: Sorry to make you do this, but post another link of the rest of the logs(I can see there are still error logs bellow that.  I suspect the culprit cause of this is down bellow.

Comment: I can tell you that all these errors are the only errors i get from my Session ( Package: com.htl.barcodescanner )

Comment: So you can't tell me where my problem is ? Would it help you if i send you my Source Code ?

Comment: Sorry still very vauge.  Post your entire project at a hosting site and post the link, I will figure it out.  I'm intrigued at this point

Comment: So i have uploaded my whole project: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/377041/Snickers-BarcodeScanner-rar.html  There is a READ ME File which explains you some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

this integration is provided by intents,so you had to have installed app which runs with specific intent (action=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN) like [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android)

i'm pretty sure that you don't have such app on your other phone and thats why you're getting "activity not found" Exception now

Edit: about diffs between IntentIntegrator and plain Intent ... well, there is no diffs beside that with IntentIntegrator you have it all nicely wrapped

Comment: So is there anyway to have the full barcode Scanner ( from Zxing ) integrated in my own App ? Edit: Thx for the fast answer

Comment: yes, but i think the IntentIntegrator way is better ... if you're using IntentIntegrator and user have no BarcodeScaner installed it should ask user to go to market and get this app ...

Comment: I know that IntentIntegrator will tell the user to install the original Barcode Scanner, but that is what i dont want. I want that the whole Barcode Scanner is in my App included and no other apps are needed.

Comment: Snickers...you definitely should have mentioned this earlier.